# export data to csv in powershell

Tags: powershell, csv

I would like to export my data to csv file, can anyone suggest me how to do it.

My data

```
  @{Id=22; AccountId=56; ActivationDate=Wed, 25 Nov 2020 12:00 AM; AssignedBy=34}
  @{Id=23; AccountId=57; ActivationDate=Sun, 01 Nov 2020 12:00 AM; AssignedBy=35}
  @{Id=24; AccountId=58; ActivationDate=Sun, 01 Nov 2020 12:00 AM; AssignedBy=36}
```

Thanks,
Mahesh K

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please show your code.

Comment: `$MyData | Export-Csv .\MyData.csv -Delimiter ';'`

Comment: Hi iRon,

I have tried this,
$testObject = [pscustomobject]$response.Content
$testObject = $testObject | ConvertTo-Csv
$testObject | Export-Csv 'D:\Safe.Csv'

And i am getting output as
#TYPE System.String
"Length"
"8223967"

Not getting in the form of csv

Comment: Please show us what exactly `$myData` is. Type `$myData.GetType().FullName`. Is that an array of hashtables? A string? How do you obtain that data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```
$mydata = @()

$mydata +=  [pscustomobject]@{Id=22; AccountId=56; ActivationDate='Wed, 25 Nov 2020 12:00 AM'; AssignedBy=34}
$mydata +=  [pscustomobject]@{Id=23; AccountId=57; ActivationDate='Sun, 01 Nov 2020 12:00 AM'; AssignedBy=35}
$mydata +=  [pscustomobject]@{Id=24; AccountId=58; ActivationDate='Sun, 01 Nov 2020 12:00 AM'; AssignedBy=36}


$mydata | Export-Csv Myfile.csv -notype
```

The first thing to do is to transform the dates in your data into strings.  This is necessary to prevent PS from trying to parse the commas, and getting mixed up.  The dates are going to be character strings in the csv file anyway.  If you want to find out the best way to express dates, ask a separate question.

The next thing I did is to transform each hashtable into a PSCustomobject.  This type of object is one that Export-csv knows how to work with.

The next thing is to collect all three items into an array, and store it in  a variable.

Finally,   I piped the resulting variable into Export-csv, providing a dummy filename.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it's a case of formatting the data as opposed to exporting to csv and so:

```
Get-Content mydata | ForEach-Object { $line=$_.replace(";",","); $strp=$line.Split("[{}]"); Write-Output $strp[1] } > csvfile.csv
```

Get each line of data in mydata and replace any ";" with ",". Split the data so we can get to the data in between "{" and "}" Print the converted lines and redirect to a new file csvfile.csv